# Some emails I send are generating hotel reservation events in gmail at google calendar, how to avoid it?

Tags: html, email, pdf, gmail

As I said on the title, we are sending to our customers invoice mails with a HTML body and and attached PDF with the invoice itself. I cannot put examples because they have confidential information.

Surprisingly some of them are generating an event of an hotel reservation on the customer gmail at google calendar. The 'reservation' code are the same as the invoice code and the name of the hotel are very similar to the address of my office, it seems like google are parsing our mails and creating automatically an event.

I know the mail markups of google https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup but I'm not using it, evenmore, what I want is to avoid this behavior for all of our mails, but the google documentations only has information about how to add this behavior, not how to avoid it.

anyone know how to avoid at all the automatically event creation in the emails by gmail? What I want is just know if there are some markup or similar for the emails to prevent it. Any solution on the customer side is not possible in our situation.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi ! Could you show a sample of the HTML email you are sending? (if it contains confidential information, make up a sample email without the invoice but with the HTML template, just replace the sensitive information with fake one) Many thanks !

Comment: Hi! first of all thanks for the answer. After some testing I've discovered the real problem it wasn't the email, it's the invoice on PDF attached to the email iself.
If I remove the address at the invoice on PDF (just two words) or evenmore, I replace it by images, gmail doesn't create automatically the hotel reservation at calendar.

It seems a google problem with his parser, I'll try to contact them because I'm pretty sure the problem is by his side.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: Any solutions? @Santiago. Same case here wiht invoices and hotel reservations form attached PDFs

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I can confirm it is from the pdf attachments because in my case there are no markups or microdata in the html. Not even meta tags.

Comment: Hi @ArmandoRodríguezAcosta , it was impossible to us contact google about this. The solution we found was, on the PDF, use an image instead of text for the address or use some official alias. We use the last option as we have a valid and official alias for the name of the street (catalan instead of spanish).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not cool that you could not contact google about this. I think this may be happening cause of the language. (spanish in my case)